# Three.js - How to convert 360 photo to texture files

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, textures, 360-virtual-reality

I've implemented something similar to [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1dy343xy/) using a texture like so:

```
            var r = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/timoxley/threejs/master/examples/textures/cube/Park3Med/";
            var urls = [
                r + "px.jpg", r + "nx.jpg",
                r + "py.jpg", r + "ny.jpg",
                r + "pz.jpg", r + "nz.jpg"
            ];
```

I'd like to use a 360 photo ([example](http://www.samsung.com/sg/gear360/images/gear-360_real360_reverse.jpg)) instead but not sure how to integrate that - should it be converted to texture or can I integrate it directly?

Comment: Take a look here: http://blog.mastermaps.com/2014/01/photo-spheres-with-threejs.html (btw, the photo needs to be cropped so it's exactly twice as wide as it is high)